# Jmeter use random string inside CSV file and resolve at runtime

Tags: csv, variables, random, dynamic, jmeter

I have CSV File where I have stored full JSON Request and using this variable in API RQ - ${Request}

inside each row of the CSV File I have added ${randomVariable}

In my test plan I use
randomVariable  ${__RandomString(10,QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM4563456345634_,)}
this generates the random variable but in the JSON instead of actual random value its passed as ${randomVariable}
I have tried using Beanshell PreProcessor with get and put but still doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want JMeter to evaluate the variables which are coming from external data sources, i.e. CSV files, you need to wrap the variable reference name into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval), to wit:

- `${variableFromCSV}` - will return `${randomVariable}`
- `${__eval(${variableFromCSV})}` - will return **the actual value** of the `${randomVariable}`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)